# A very frustrated issue that occurs in Samsung Tablet devices

Tags: android, crash-reports, samsung-mobile

I am completely not aware that which part of my code makes this crash. 
I use photoview, picasso, google analytics, FAB appcompat, cardview, libraries in my app. A single clue that I have is it occurs only in below Samsung tablet kinda devices.

- Samsung Galaxy Tab4 10.0
- Samsung Galaxy Note Pro 12.2
- Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro 12.2
- Samsung Galaxy TabS 10.5

Please help me on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Crash logs are below:

```
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/chagallltevl/chagallltecan:4.4.2/KOT49H/T805WVLU1ANG6:user/release-keys'
Revision: '7'
pid: 17790, tid: 17790, name: com.companyname.product >>> com.companyname.product <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
r0 00000000 r1 0000457e r2 00000006 r3 00000000
r4 00000006 r5 0000000c r6 0000457e r7 0000010c
r8 bef6c368 r9 417a5bf0 sl 418a8038 fp bef6c37c
ip 402a62c4 sp bef6c2c0 lr 4013a0e1 pc 401492d0 cpsr 000e0010
d0 746f626f522f7372 d1 616c756765522d2e
d2 7461642f3a706974 d3 6f632f7070612f74
d4 8000000000000000 d5 44954000422c0000
d6 0000000000000000 d7 422c00000000002b
d8 0000000000000000 d9 0000000000000000
d10 0000000000000000 d11 0000000000000000
d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 0000000000000000 d17 3ff0000000000000
d18 0000000000000000 d19 3ff0000000000000
d20 0000000000000000 d21 0000000000000000
d22 0000000000000000 d23 0000000000000000
d24 0000000000000000 d25 0000000000000000
d26 3ff0000000000000 d27 0000000000000000
d28 3ff0000000000000 d29 0000000000000000
d30 0000000000000000 d31 0000000000000000
scr 60000013

backtrace:
#00 pc 000222d0 /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01 pc 000130dd /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
#02 pc 000132f1 /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
#03 pc 00012027 /system/lib/libc.so
#04 pc 00021b84 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
#05 pc 00000921 /system/lib/libstdc++.so (operator new(unsigned int)+8)
#06 pc 0000cfd5 /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (android::_CompressedAsset::getBuffer(bool)+12)
#07 pc 00085339 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#08 pc 0001eacc /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#09 pc 0004f04b /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
#10 pc 00027ee0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#11 pc 0002ef14 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#12 pc 0002c578 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#13 pc 0006172d /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+392)
#14 pc 00069acf /system/lib/libdvm.so
#15 pc 00027ee0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#16 pc 0002ef14 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#17 pc 0002c578 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#18 pc 00061449 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
#19 pc 0004ac33 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#20 pc 0005251b /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#21 pc 00053aaf /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+354)
#22 pc 0000105b /system/bin/app_process
#23 pc 0000e45f /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+50)
#24 pc 00000d7c /system/bin/app_process

code around pc:
401492b0 e8bd00f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000 
401492c0 ea006e86 e92d50f0 e3a07f43 ef000000 
401492d0 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000 
401492e0 ea006e7e e92d50f0 e3a070ee ef000000 
401492f0 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000 
40149300 ea006e76 e1520003 8a00008c f5d1f040 
40149310 e92d4001 e3520010 3a000024 e2603000 
40149320 e213300f 0a00000e e0422003 e1b0cf83 
40149330 44d1e001 44c0e001 24d1c001 24d1e001 
40149340 24c0c001 24c0e001 e1b0ce83 aa000001 
40149350 f4a1030d f480031d 3a000001 f421070d 
40149360 f400071d e2522040 3a000006 f421020d 
40149370 f421420d f5d1f100 e2522040 f400022d 
40149380 f400422d 2afffff8 e2922020 3a000002 
40149390 f421020d e2422020 f400022d e2822020 
401493a0 e3120010 0a000001 f4210a0d f4000a2d 

code around lr:
4013a0c0 447b4b13 42b3e010 4812d10e 44786a1e 
4013a0d0 ec90f7fb ea42f00d 46224631 e8f2f00f 
4013a0e0 d00a3001 e00b2400 2b00681b 480ad1eb 
4013a0f0 44782403 ec7ef7fb f001e002 6804fa87 
4013a100 fa84f001 46206005 bf00bd70 0003b2e2 
4013a110 0003b2d6 0003b2ce 0003b2aa bf7ef7ff 
4013a120 4a3e4b3d 43f0e92d 4606b08b 447b460d 
4013a130 6823589c 930946a1 fa68f001 8000f8d0 
4013a140 d0482d00 f00f4628 280fffc3 d8444604 
4013a150 ffe4f7ff d1064286 4629200f e90cf00d 
4013a160 d03c2800 482ee02e f7fb4478 482debc2 
4013a170 e0154478 d11342b0 482b6a06 f7fb4478 
4013a180 4a2aec3a 46332120 447aa801 fb44f013 
4013a190 a8012101 fe46f01a 46061c42 e011d104 
4013a1a0 28006800 e02cd1e6 46294630 f00d4622 
4013a1b0 1c43e948 d11e4607 fa28f001 29046801
```

Comment: These stack traces are originating from a native library. The Tab 3 was intel based and would need different versions of this native library, if the Tab 4 is also intel based you would need to make sure that the intel versions are included and loaded if needed

Comment: Hi @CurlyPaul, any solution for this issue.?   Please help me.

Comment: Well like I said, check which on architectures of the devices that are having this problem and if they are all the same as each other and different to the ones that do work then you need to find out which library is causing this and swap it for the right one for that chipset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root cause of the issue. I am using custom font in my app. So whenever I initialize the custom font, I should have added the code like

```
if(robotoRegularTypeFace == null)
    {
        robotoRegularTypeFace   =   Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
    }
```

If I didn't add this if check, the memory will be leaked.